# How to stop a certain event on rich:faces components from firing?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a component which for example a rich:scrollableDataTable that has a onrowclick event functionality.

What i wanted to do is at a certain condition i don't want the event to be fired.
How can i achieve this? Is there a way to do this?

Im getting error on this:

```
onRowClick="#{_xFolder.editmode == false ? 'Event.stop(event);' : 'setFolder('#{_xFolder.id.xFolderObjectID}');'}"
```

the setFolder is the function name that will be invoke when edit mode is true; 
btw, im using a4j:jsFunction on this event.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the onclick event from firing on your RF component, you specify:

```
onclick="#{someCondition == true ? 'Event.stop(event);' : ''}"
```

But I'm not sure it works for onrowclick.

Comment: its work on rowclick. but i am getting problem on putting function name inside the second output condition.